# Ssearching for string containing newline character in powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to detect if the string in line 1 is present in filename without confusing it with the string in line 2 since the text in line 1 is a substring of the text in line 2. I have tried the code below but it is not detect it correctly.

My powershell script:

```
$s1 = 'Hello world'
$s2 = "`n"
[int]$result = Get-Content filename | Select-String $s1+$s2 -quiet
Write-Host "result : " $result
```

Where the content of the filename is:

```
"line1: xxxxxx Hello world"
"line2: yyyyyy Hello world and some more text"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there are quotes after `hello world` then use:

```
Select-String -Path filename -Pattern 'hello world"$' | Select-Object *
```

otherwise

```
Select-String -Path filename -Pattern 'hello world$' | Select-Object *
```

Note: The `$` represents end of the line

Comment: Solved. Thank you kindly